# Arithmetic overflow error while executing T-SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select COUNT(*)  from T1,T2
```

In the above query I just try to get the number of possible permutation combination can be made. 
Both are very huge table which have `27182708` rows.

When I try to execute above query it throws `Arithmetic overflow error`.

I have tried `bigint` conversion also but same response.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [COUNT_BIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx) instead.  This will return a `bigint` instead of an `int`, which may solve your problem.

Also, while it probably doesn't make a huge difference here, using ANSI Joins is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: You will need to cast those numbers as `bigint` before you multiply them.